# Use Excel to do core analysis in a PHP application?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I think this is really a question about approach.

We have a core Excel spreadsheet that comes in from a third party, and it provides some complex analysis of raw data. The raw data arrives directly from customers in a second spreadsheet.

We are looking to create an automated web-server based system where the raw data Excel file can be uploaded and the analysis performed, and a report generated.

The report generation is no problem, but is there any mileage in actually using the core Excel spreadsheet itself within the application to do the mathematics (using PHPExcel for example)? Or is the best approach always to replicate the analysis in code?

Our thinking is that the analysis (which comes in from a third party) is fairly complex, so will take quite a lot of unpicking to replicate in PHP, and secondly parts of the analysis are often being tweaked by the third party meaning new versions of the Excel are regularly provided to us.

I could imagine using PHPExcel to do something like this, creating the sheet in memory and merging the raw data in as a second worksheet, then reading out the calculated results, but is this realistic - would it be too slow - or just simply not work how I am imagining?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't have much familiarity with PHPExcel so I don't know how faithfully it reproduces Excel's calculation engine.  I would say however that in general terms, it's better to reuse a working solution than to reimplement it.  Having two different versions of something intended to do the same job leads to maintainence headaches later.

Comment: Indeed, that was my gut feeling too. Especially as the core analysis seems to get pulled about and changed quite a lot.

Comment: Looking into the exact same problem with a complex Excel-file. How did this go? I am very curios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of the Excel formulae, it can be perfectly viable to use PHPExcel's calculation engine, but you'd need to watch out for a few potential "gotchas".

- Not all Excel functions are fully supported (There is a list provided
  in the PHPExcel documentation, but I think 316 functions out of 356
  are now supported)
- Excel functions from the analysis toolpack are not
  supported for BIFF (.xls) workbooks; though they will work with
  OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) workbooks
- User-defined functions are not
  supported
- Macros and other VB code are not supported
- Array formulae
  are not yet supported (this is a significant part of the planned
  rewrite of the calculation engine due to start by the end of the year)
- R1C1 format for cell references is not supported

It is relatively slow (part of the reason it needs a rewrite). You could certainly write PHP code that would execute the formulae you need more efficiently, because you could code to your specific requirements. Whether PHPExcel would be too slow? Only you can determine what "too slow" actually means.

Note that it's often better to submit requests for extensive memory- or time-consuming tasks to run outside of the web server

On the other hand, if your client ever changes their spreadsheet (and you indicate that this is fairly frequent), then using PHPExcel's built-in calculation engine means that it would still work without problems, whereas custom-written code would need modification.
As you've already pointed out, complex formulae could require a lot of work converting to PHP code; and unpicking changes made to formulae in a spreadsheet would be particularly difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, and the list of gotchas. I'll get the Excel supported functions list over to the people who author the analysis sheet, and see how it looks to them. If it were more of a static thing it would make sense to code it in PHP, but that's not been our experience so far - it's been a changing and evolving analysis. Good point too about what 'slow' really means, and would depend so much on future volume of data. Currently I don't think slow would be too much of a problem. I think it is now worth me setting up some experiments.

Comment: UPDATE: Some more research into this has led me to the conclusion that the lack of support for array formula in PHPExcel, as you highlighted Mark, would be quite a problem in this instance. The Excel sheets we get make full use of arrays. I'll keep on searching...

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution to your problem, but the preferred approach would be you build the calculations PHP-side, and then get clients/third-parties to submit data in a specified format (and ideally as a CSV file), and then you parse the data and perform any necessary calculations.

Comment: Thanks Martin, indeed I can see that PHP handling the analysis directly takes the 'excel' layer out of the processing. One problem we have is that the guys that do the analysis are very much Excel people, and the whole process rotates around their spreadsheets, and always has. It's the frequent changes to that which are causing us to scratch our heads here. We fear constant changes to replicate the core analysis in our PHP. I wonder if there is any more basic way to pull the maths out of an excel sheet, or to define the maths in some other way.