# Run excel formula from php

Tags: php, excel, excel-formula

Here's my clients scenario my client wants to put a excel file on server now from a PHP form
sends data to the file runs a formula in this excel file and get the results.

I don't know if this is possible. 
If so direct me to a library best was PHP, or some other possible solutions.

Comment: What about just porting the xls file to PHP + a 2D database? Or will there be multiple different files, updated regularly?

Comment: Why don't you apply the excel logic on a php file and output as a excel sheet

Comment: I'ts not possible because the logis as my client claims will change too often. So I would need a solution that grabs the formula and changes it to PHP logic grabbing all the data from excel file along the way. (different values from cell's in file)

Comment: Did you collect the calculated values from excel file with getCalculatedValue()? If yes, then can you show me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's perfectly possible: take a look at the [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library which has a built-in calculation engine for handling most Excel formulae

There's an example of populating an Excel file with data (in this case from a form input) then rendering a formula in that Excel file to generate a result an ddisplaying it to a web browser in the /Tests/ directory of the distribution. This simple example /Quadratic.php solves a quadratic equation; but the principle is similar enough

**EDIT**

See my response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636964/use-excel-to-do-core-analysis-in-a-php-application) for some indication of the limitations of PHPExcel's calculation engine

**EDIT 2**

The **PHPExcel** is deprecated, hence now you can use [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in the wrong direction. Instead trying to send the data to the excel file, read the excel file in you PHP script and do the math there.

Trying to send dynamic data into a static XLS file wont work.

And you can add a regular cronjob, that checks if the XLS file data has changed, if it has, then run your calculation again.

Comment: Try sending a php script into .txt file, what will the results be?

Comment: Yes that's what I've tried to explain to the client but he sais that the formula will change so much that its not possible for him to provide me with the formulas.

Comment: Well... then just read the formula from the xls file and recreate it in your php script. That will work.

Comment: @Dainis - what's a txt file got to do with anything?

Comment: Because from PHPs view, `.xls` or `.txt` is just a static file. But yes, if you are right, there might be a way to do what OP wants in the 1st place.

Comment: It's only a static file if PHP treats it as a static file, but any file where you can read, update and write again is no longer a static file